# C# custom variables

Tags: c#

I was experimenting with making a custom variables but got stuck.

I'm still new to C# so it's only expected for me to not know what's happening, I guess..

```
struct MyCustomStringVariable
{
    public static implicit operator MyCustomStringVariable(string input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static MyCustomStringVariable myCustomString = "This is a string!";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myCustomString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Comment: Your implicit operator implementation is not correct. How do you make that compiling?

Comment: Did not exactly understood what you mean by "How do you do that compiling" but since my implicit operator implementation is not correct, how exactly should I do that in a correct manner?

Comment: What is your end goal? Defining operators is very rare in C#, are you sure you don't just want a type (a `class` or `struct`) with a `string` field?

Comment: whatever thought process has led you to thinking you need to create custom operators is incorrect. They are level 500 things. The Q title says you are trying to do something totally un related to the code u show ('custom variables'). So - what are u actually trying to do?

Comment: @pm100 what are level 500 things?

Comment: My final goal is to visualize the process of making a string variable in my head so that I can better understand the concept behind it.

Comment: @JonathonChase I mean covered in the CS5xxx classes not in CS1xxx classes. College classes not c# classes. "CS504 creating custom conversion operators in c#"

Comment: `My final goal is to visualize the process of making a string variable in my head so that I can better understand the concept behind it.` <= I am not sure what a new type as well as an implicit operator how to do with this?

Comment: tip for a beginner: avoid messing around with operator at all cost

Comment: Tip for beginners: Accept that if you follow the syntax correctly, things will work. If you truly want to see how the string class in c# works you can find the reference source here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs Keep in mind this is some pretty advanced code and you aren't likely, as a beginner, to understand much if any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the implicit operator is called recursively. You'll need to implement your structure as so, encapsulating your string variable somehow.

```
struct MyCustomStringVariable
{
    private string value;

    public MyCustomStringVariable(string input)
    {
        value = input;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyCustomStringVariable(string input)
    {
        return new MyCustomStringVariable(input);
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, calling it like

```
Console.WriteLine(myCustomString.GetValue());
```

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-implement-user-defined-conversions-between-structs).

Comment: Is there a way I can accept both answers, I think both of them were really helpful?

Comment: @Dan - [so] only allows for a single marked answer per question. Once you have enough reputation you can up-vote each submitted answer once and later on you can also downvote each submitted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the code is stuck in an infinit loop. Your implicit operator will call itself because it returns the original input string which does not throw an exception because of the defined operator.

```
public static implicit operator MyCustomStringVariable(string input)
{
    return input; // returning string type will call this method again
}
```

should be

```
public static implicit operator MyCustomStringVariable(string input)
{
    // and use input somewhere on the returned type
    return new MyCustomStringVariable(); 
}
```

---

That said there is probably no reason for you to define a type named `MyCustomStringVariable` but that is hard to tell because you never share the code for this or how you intend to use it.

---

> My final goal is to visualize the process of making a string variable in my head so that I can better understand the concept behind it.

I am not sure how your custom struct or its implicit operator fit in with this goal. Why not just use the type `string`?

```
static string myCustomString  = "This is a string!";
```

Comment: The big question is: why the compiler compiled this without errors or at least warnings? The retrun type isn't `MyCustomStringVariable` :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound - Because of the operator. This compiles just fine as do other infinit recursive loops, it is a logic error not a syntax error.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Sure it is! There's an implicit conversion from the `return` statement's type to the return type. It just so happens to be implemented by the very same operator implementation.

Comment: @Igor & Joe Sewell: I understand the stack overflow exception. What I don't understand why the compiler didn't detect that the same implicit conversion is used to convert the returned value.

Comment: @CodeNotFound You've defined a conversion from string to `MyCustom`. Your conversion returns a string, not a `MyCustom`. The compiler asks "Is there an implicit conversion from string to `MyCustom`?" There is, so it compiles along.

Comment: @CodeNotFound - Compilers fail on syntax errors which the code does not have. It would not surprise me though if there was a warning or log message generated by the IDE.

Comment: @JonathonChase when you defined the implicit conversion you already put the return type in the conversion defintiion `public static implicit operator MyCustom` so the compiler should be smart to force you to return tha type or subtype.

Comment: @CodeNotFound This would break cases where multiple conversions may take place. Perhaps we add an int to `MyCustom` conversion, and we want to take advantage of the fact that we already have a string conversion, so we just return `someInt.ToString()`, then let the string conversion do it's thing.